# Preventing threads in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, debugging

I am starting to learn Objective-C, and am using Xcode, but every time I run the program, a thread is run, and prevents any of the code to work. Can you guys explain how I can deal with this? And educate me on it a little bit? I have written a simple console log to demonstrate my problem. Once again, I am new to Xcode and Objective-C, so I need some basic explanation.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4GWH.png]
 *Click image for bigger version*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is quite unclear at the moment, it's difficult to tell what you are asking. Could you specify where you are seeing these threads and why you think they are a problem. Screenshots will help, and although you aren't able to post them yet, if you post a link to a screenshot, we can edit your question to include it.

Comment: The way to prevent threads is to simply not write code that spins out new threads.  All of your code, by default, executes in the main thread.  You must have at least one thread.  Beyond this, if you want any help, you need to provide significantly more detail here.

Comment: Yeah, as per James Webster, could you please indicate the evidence that leads to your conclusion? At the minute it sounds more like "my code isn't working so I observed one thing that is happening and decided that's definitely to blame".

Comment: I posted the link to a screenshot, thank you for the help.

Comment: This simply means there is a bug in your code. Do not mess with threads if you are new to Xcode, you'll cause more problems for yourself. The main or @autorelease part of your function simply means that an exception (not error) has occurred. (Exception red X - error yellow !). Look at your code using break point and email me at development@dreamthegame.com with your code snippet if you have issues.

Comment: You should leave the image in @JadenRanzenberger, it's crucial to the question

Answer (score 4):

*I've **highlighted** some of the keywords you might have to research before you want to continue*

---

I think you've misunderstood the Xcode **IDE**. You're code has stopped executing, because the **debugger** hit a **breakpoint**.

Hitting a breakpoint usually causes the "Debug navigator" (the panel on the left) to be shown. This panel lists the **threads** running in your program and the **stack trace** for each thread.

Your program always has *at least one* thread. This is called the **main thread**.

---

Your program, even without breakpoints, won't do anything. You aren't calling any **methods** (or **functions**)(or strictly in Objective-C, "**messages**"). You have made several fundamental mistakes with this very simple program. You might do better to follow some tutorials rather than just jumping in.

Comment: I have found my stupid mistake. After inserting some test code into the main, I realized that I did have a breakpoint before the code was executed, which triggered the debugger, and the result never showed up in the log, I am sorry for wasting your time, just a dumb mistake that I should have noticed earlier.

Comment: No problem. There's no need to say thanks, the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you is to upvote or accept answers. You can do this by clicking the little up arrow next to answers (when you have enough rep) and clicking the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with threads. There is always a thread called the "main thread." That's normal and required (your code has to run in *some* context).

The above code doesn't run because you never call your function. In C (which ObjC is a superset of), the `main()` function is run automatically. Your `main()` function does nothing, and immediately returns, so the program will just exit. You need to call your function if you want it to run.

Cocoanetics provides a [brief introduction](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/command-line-tools-tutorial-1/) to building a non-trivial command-line app in ObjC.